# Generating an ordered selection with repetition of designated length of entry

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, sage

I am writing a function kind of mimicking `unordered_tuple` from the [sage combinatorial functions](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/combinat.html) available in python.

It differs, though, in that the input set I am using is always [10, 9, 8, 7, 6], and only the number of entry varies (not larger than 10).

So, the desired output for entry = 3 and for entry = 4 is,

```
unordered_tuples([10,9,8,7,6], 3)
[[6, 6, 6],
 [6, 6, 7],
 [6, 6, 8],
 [6, 6, 9],
 [6, 6, 10],
 [6, 7, 7],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [6, 7, 9],
 [6, 7, 10],
 [6, 8, 8],
 [6, 8, 9],
 [6, 8, 10],
 [6, 9, 9],
 [6, 9, 10],
 [6, 10, 10],
 [7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 8],
 [7, 7, 9],
 [7, 7, 10],
 [7, 8, 8],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [7, 8, 10],
 [7, 9, 9],
 [7, 9, 10],
 [7, 10, 10],
 [8, 8, 8],
 [8, 8, 9],
 [8, 8, 10],
 [8, 9, 9],
 [8, 9, 10],
 [8, 10, 10],
 [9, 9, 9],
 [9, 9, 10],
 [9, 10, 10],
 [10, 10, 10]]

unordered_tuples([10,9,8,7,6], 4)
[[6, 6, 6, 6],
 [6, 6, 6, 7],
 [6, 6, 6, 8],
 [6, 6, 6, 9],
 [6, 6, 6, 10],
 [6, 6, 7, 7],
 [6, 6, 7, 8],
 [6, 6, 7, 9],
 [6, 6, 7, 10],
 [6, 6, 8, 8],
 [6, 6, 8, 9],
 [6, 6, 8, 10],
 [6, 6, 9, 9],
 [6, 6, 9, 10],
 [6, 6, 10, 10],
 [6, 7, 7, 7],
 [6, 7, 7, 8],
 [6, 7, 7, 9],
 [6, 7, 7, 10],
 [6, 7, 8, 8],
 [6, 7, 8, 9],
 [6, 7, 8, 10],
 [6, 7, 9, 9],
 [6, 7, 9, 10],
 [6, 7, 10, 10],
 [6, 8, 8, 8],
 [6, 8, 8, 9],
 [6, 8, 8, 10],
 [6, 8, 9, 9],
 [6, 8, 9, 10],
 [6, 8, 10, 10],
 [6, 9, 9, 9],
 [6, 9, 9, 10],
 [6, 9, 10, 10],
 [6, 10, 10, 10],
 [7, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 8],
 [7, 7, 7, 9],
 [7, 7, 7, 10],
 [7, 7, 8, 8],
 [7, 7, 8, 9],
 [7, 7, 8, 10],
 [7, 7, 9, 9],
 [7, 7, 9, 10],
 [7, 7, 10, 10],
 [7, 8, 8, 8],
 [7, 8, 8, 9],
 [7, 8, 8, 10],
 [7, 8, 9, 9],
 [7, 8, 9, 10],
 [7, 8, 10, 10],
 [7, 9, 9, 9],
 [7, 9, 9, 10],
 [7, 9, 10, 10],
 [7, 10, 10, 10],
 [8, 8, 8, 8],
 [8, 8, 8, 9],
 [8, 8, 8, 10],
 [8, 8, 9, 9],
 [8, 8, 9, 10],
 [8, 8, 10, 10],
 [8, 9, 9, 9],
 [8, 9, 9, 10],
 [8, 9, 10, 10],
 [8, 10, 10, 10],
 [9, 9, 9, 9],
 [9, 9, 9, 10],
 [9, 9, 10, 10],
 [9, 10, 10, 10],
 [10, 10, 10, 10]]
```

and the c++ function I wrote follows.

I am actually not an experienced programmer, and I just tried to come up with the right solution, but it is working correctly, but it gives a lot of repetitive solutions.

Honestly, I wrote the function, but I don't even know what I wrote.

I could use `set`, but it would be very inefficient and I want to know the correct solution for this problem.

Can anyone fix it so that it gives the output above?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int> > ut(int);

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        int entry = atoi(argv[1]);
        ut(entry);
        return 1;
    }

    vector<vector<int> > ut(int entry) {
        vector<vector<int> > ret;

        int upper = 10;
        vector<int> v(entry, upper);
        ret.push_back(v);

        typedef vector<int>::iterator iter_t;

        iter_t it = v.begin();
        int count=0;
        int c = 0;
        while(v.back() != 6) {
            v = ret[count+c];
            while(it != v.end()) {
                --(*it);
                ++it;
                ret.push_back(v);
                ++c;
            }
            it = v.begin();
            c=0;
            ++count;
        }


        for(int i=0; i<ret.size(); ++i) {
            vector<int> tuple = ret[i];
            for(int j=0; j<tuple.size(); ++j) {
                cout << tuple[j] << ' ';
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Get the functionality correct first, worry about efficiency later.

Comment: The function works correctly if I just change the return type from vector to set. I am not sure if my algorithm is 'good' or not

Comment: This code appears to produce undefined behavior. Do you want us to show you where it's wrong and how to fix it, or give you an algorithm that works?

Comment: Do you mean `set<vector<int>>`?

Comment: @Beta either way. Better if both. Thank you.

Comment: @n.m. right, but actually I haven't tested it because I did not want to do it that way

Comment: didn't you you ask this same question already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490246/translating-unordered-tuple-function-in-sage-to-c? I don't know how this is seen on stackoverflow. As there are more comments on this version (and I've just edited it to include the link to the original python functions), I would drop the other question if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
vector<vector<int> > ret;

int upper = 10;
vector<int> v(entry, upper);
ret.push_back(v);

typedef vector<int>::iterator iter_t;

iter_t it = v.begin();
int count=0;
int c = 0;
while(v.back() != 6) {
  v = ret[count+c];
  while(it != v.end()) {
    --(*it);
    ++it;
    ret.push_back(v);
    ++c;
  }
  it = v.begin();
  c=0;
  ++count;
}
```

This is just *scary*. (I understand that you're a beginner; please understand that my criticism is intended to help.) Usually this kind if dense complexity is unnecessary and serves as a hiding place for bugs. Notice that `c` and `it` are set *before* the loop and *at the end* of the loop, and never used again; we can set them *at the beginning* of the loop, and the code will be shorter and clearer:

```
int count=0;
while(v.back() != 6) {
  iter_t it = v.begin();
  int c = 0;
  v = ret[count+c];
  while(it != v.end()) {
    --(*it);
    ++it;
    ret.push_back(v);
    ++c;
  }
  ++count;
}
```

Now we can see that `c` *is never used except when it's zero*. (Look at the original code if you don't believe me.) But what's much worse is that `it` points into `v`, and then `v` is assigned a new value. So `it` probably points into dead memory, and dereferencing it causes undefined behavior. And it's not clear how this code is intended to work anyway.

**Try this:**

```
vector<int> v(n,6);

vector<int>::iterator itr1;
do{
  ret.push_back(v);

  itr1 = v.begin();

  while(++(*itr1)>10){
      if(++itr1==v.end())
        break;
  }
  for(vector<int>::iterator itr2 = v.begin(); itr2!=itr1; ++itr2)
    *itr2 = *itr1;
}
while(itr1!=v.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start with permutation problems is **recursion**. Taking this approach, to build all the outputs of length 3, you choose a digit from your set `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, and then append to it all the outputs of length 2, with the input set constrained to start from the digit chosen. So, if, e.g. you chose `7`, your input set for the first recursive call would be `[ 7, 8, 9, 10]`. I.e., the recursive call in this case would be append to `[ 7 ]` all outputs of length `2` from the input `[ 7, 8, 9, 10]`

A program that implements this idea is below. I'd be interested to see if anyone can come up with a non-recursive solution.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
typedef std::vector<intvec> intvecs;

void GenerateUnOrderedIntVecs(
    const int* remainingInput, int remainingInputLen, 
    const intvec& outputSoFar, int remainingOutputLen,
    intvecs& output)
{
    if (remainingOutputLen == 0) { // base case of recursion
        output.push_back(outputSoFar);
        return;
    }

    // For all digits in our input
    for(int i=0; i<remainingInputLen; ++i) {
        // Add the ith digit to our output so far
        intvec outputSoFar2(outputSoFar);
        outputSoFar2.push_back(remainingInput[i]);
        // The recursion
        GenerateUnOrderedIntVecs(
            remainingInput + i,    // input set constrained to start from chosen digit
            remainingInputLen - i, // input set is shorter
            outputSoFar2,          // one digit longer than the parameter outputSoFar
            remainingOutputLen -1, // so we need one digit less as we recurse
            output);
    }
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int nToChooseFrom = 5;
    const int nToChooose = 3;
    const int input[nToChooseFrom] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; // provide input in sorted order (or sort it!)

    intvecs output;
    GenerateUnOrderedIntVecs(
        input, nToChooseFrom,
        intvec(), nToChooose,
        output);

    for(intvecs::const_iterator i=output.begin(); i!=output.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        const intvec& unordered_tuple = *i;
        for(intvec::const_iterator j = unordered_tuple.begin(); j!=unordered_tuple.end(); ++j) {
            std::cout << *j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work on both your examples (but I only checked the first thoroughly). If you can't see how it works by reading the code, a good approach would be to run it in a debugger (that's what I had to do to get it to work!:)